# How to detect string is `article/page/inc/3/4` has `inc` in last third index of `/`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How to detect string is `article/page/inc/3/4` has `inc` in last third index of `/`?
and get the last second index of `/` above example is `3`?

I have two different string, 1: 'article/page/4' , 2: `article/page/inc/3/4`,
I can get 1: 'article/page/4' last string = 4, like below:

```
var current_path_fragment = 'article/page/4';  
var last = current_path_fragment.substring(current_path_fragment.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

I tried to find how to detect if string have `inc` and get second string `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `regular expression`

```
/^([^/]+)*\/([^/]+)*\/inc\/([^/]+)*\/([^/]+)*/
```

The full code would then be

```
var regex = /^([^/]+)*\/([^/]+)*\/inc\/([^/]+)*\/([^/]+)*/; 
var input = "your input string"; 
if(regex.test(input)) {
    var match = input.match(regex);
    alert(match); // Then you will have all the data you want in the match array 
} else {
  alert("No matches found!");
}
```

Check the `match` variable then to retrieve all the data you want.

---

[image]

Comment: @Tomas Lycken I have this very useful regex testing website :) http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the String

If `s` is `article/page/inc/3/4`,

```
s.split('/')
```

gives an array with five elements `article`, `page`, `inc`, `3` and `4`.

When [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) this array

```
var elements = s.split('/').reverse();
```

`elements[0]` will have the last segment (`4` in your case), `elements[1]` will have the second from last (`3` in your case) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

this will check to see if the string contains **inc** or not, if it contains it, it will give you the second last part of the string.

```
var current_path_fragment = 'article/page/4';
if(current_path_fragment.indexOf("inc")){
    var splittedString= current_path_fragment.split('/').reverse();
    var secondLastPart= splittedString[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to make use of the [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [`lastIndexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp).

For example, to see if the string contains `inc` anywhere, you can check if `'yourstring'.indexOf('inc') >= 0` - if it is, then the string has `inc` in it. Additionally, if the string contains `inc`, you already know where in the string to start searching for the next element.

```
var s = 'article/something/inc/3/4';
incidx = s.indexOf('inc');

if (incidx >= 0) {
    // 'inc' starts at incidx, so the next element starts at incidx+4. Get it!
    result = s.substr(incidx+4, s.indexOf('/', incidx+4));
} else {
    // no 'inc' in s, get last element.
    result = s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('/'));
}
```